# WPF: TemplateBinding to StrokeThickness of Shape does not work?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, templatebinding

Looks like the following Ellipse in ControlTemplate does not get the BorderThickness, but why?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="EllipseControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse 
                Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" 
                Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" 
                Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox
        Template="{DynamicResource EllipseControlTemplate}" 
        Foreground="Green"
        BorderThickness="15" />
</Grid>
```

TemplateBinding to `Foreground` works just fine, the ellipse is green. But to `StrokeThickness` it doesn't seem to work, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BorderThickness` is not that easy, it is a struct of type `Thickness` (and can be composite, like `BorderThickness=".0,.0,2,2"`), while `StrokeThickness` property is of type `double`.

You need `IValueConverter` to make this binding work.

Comment: I apologize, I found the answer myself already. See the answer I wrote... You probably meant that.

Comment: Good for you :) Still, mine was earlier :)

Comment: Thats true! I will choose yours as solution if you mention the Type difference, it's the key here.

Answer (score 17):

Another possible solution ... (because i like to only use IValueConverters as a last resort, and changing the DataContext of the Ellipse might not work if you need it to be set to something else):

```
<Ellipse StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness.Top}" />
```

This is equivalent to the original intent (to bind to the TemplatedParent), but using the long-hand markup allows you to specify a Path rather than just a property

Comment: Nit-pick on this great answer: I think `BorderThickness.Left` actually be the preferred value to use since it is the first value. See [this answer about margin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522026/1518546) but [the order is the same for Thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.thickness#xaml-values).

Answer (score 1):

There was naming gotcha: `BorderThickness` is type of `Thickness`, and `StrokeThickness` is type of `double`. So we need `IValueConverter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the DataContext property of the Ellipse:

```
<Ellipse DataContext="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Top}" />
```

Hope this helps!